# Redis deployed in AWS - Connection time out from localhost SpringBoot app

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, kubernetes, redis

Small question regarding Redis deployed in AWS (not AWS Elastic Cache) and an issue connecting to it.

Here is the setup of the Redis deployed in AWS: (pasting only the Kubernetes StatefulSet and Service)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  serviceName: redis
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: config
          image: redis:7.0.5-alpine
          command: [ "sh", "-c" ]
          args:
            - |
              cp /tmp/redis/redis.conf /etc/redis/redis.conf
              
              echo "finding master..."
              MASTER_FDQN=`hostname  -f | sed -e 's/redis-[0-9]\./redis-0./'`
              if [ "$(redis-cli -h sentinel -p 5000 ping)" != "PONG" ]; then
                echo "master not found, defaulting to redis-0"
              
                if [ "$(hostname)" = "redis-0" ]; then
                  echo "this is redis-0, not updating config..."
                else
                  echo "updating redis.conf..."
                  echo "slaveof $MASTER_FDQN 6379" >> /etc/redis/redis.conf
                fi
              else
                echo "sentinel found, finding master"
                MASTER="$(redis-cli -h sentinel -p 5000 sentinel get-master-addr-by-name mymaster | grep -E '(^redis-\d{1,})|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})')"
                echo "master found : $MASTER, updating redis.conf"
                echo "slaveof $MASTER 6379" >> /etc/redis/redis.conf
              fi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: redis-config
              mountPath: /etc/redis/
            - name: config
              mountPath: /tmp/redis/
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: redis:7.0.5-alpine
          command: ["redis-server"]
          args: ["/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379
              name: redis
          volumeMounts:
            - name: data
              mountPath: /data
            - name: redis-config
              mountPath: /etc/redis/
      volumes:
        - name: redis-config
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: redis-config
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: data
      spec:
        accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
        storageClassName: nfs-1
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 50Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
      name: redis
  selector:
    app: redis
  type: LoadBalancer
```

The pods are healthy, I can exec into it and perform operations fine. Here is the get all:

```
NAME          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/redis-0   1/1     Running   0          22h
pod/redis-1   1/1     Running   0          22h
pod/redis-2   1/1     Running   0          22h

NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/redis   LoadBalancer   192.168.45.55   10.51.5.2     6379:30315/TCP   26h

NAME                     READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/redis   3/3     22h
```

Here is the describe of the service:

```
Name:                     redis
Namespace:                Namespace
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=redis
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       192.168.22.33
IPs:                      192.168.22.33
LoadBalancer Ingress:     10.51.5.2
Port:                     redis  6379/TCP
TargetPort:               6379/TCP
NodePort:                 redis  30315/TCP
Endpoints:                192.xxx:6379,192.xxx:6379,192.xxx:6379
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type    Reason        Age                From                Message
  ----    ------        ----               ----                -------
  Normal  IPAllocated   68s                metallb-controller  Assigned IP ["10.51.5.2"]
  Normal  nodeAssigned  58s (x5 over 66s)  metallb-speaker     announcing from node "someaddress.com" with protocol "bgp"
  Normal  nodeAssigned  58s (x5 over 66s)  metallb-speaker     announcing from node "someaddress.com" with protocol "bgp"
```

I then try to connect to it, i.e. inserting some data with a very straightforward Spring Boot application. The application has no business logic, just trying to insert data.
Here are the relevant parts:

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory reactiveRedisConnectionFactory() {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory("10.51.5.2", 30315);
    }

@Repository
public class RedisRepository {

    private final ReactiveRedisOperations<String, String> reactiveRedisOperations;

    public RedisRepository(ReactiveRedisOperations<String, String> reactiveRedisOperations) {
        this.reactiveRedisOperations = reactiveRedisOperations;
    }

    public Mono<RedisPojo> save(RedisPojo redisPojo) {
        return reactiveRedisOperations.opsForValue().set(redisPojo.getInput(), redisPojo.getOutput()).map(__ -> redisPojo);
    }
```

Each time I am trying to write the data, I am getting this exception:

```
2022-12-02T20:20:08.015+08:00 ERROR 1184 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [8f16a752-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/save"

org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.translateException(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1602) ~[spring-data-redis-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.redis.controller.RedisController#test(RedisRequest) [DispatcherHandler]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/save" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.translateException(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1602) ~[spring-data-redis-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]

Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to 10.51.5.2/<unresolved>:30315
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:78) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.1.RELEASE.jar:6.2.1.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:56) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.1.RELEASE.jar:6.2.1.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.getConnection(AbstractRedisClient.java:350) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.1.RELEASE.jar:6.2.1.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:216) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.1.RELEASE.jar:6.2.1.RELEASE]

Caused by: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.51.5.2:30315
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:261) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
```

This is particularly puzzling, because I am quite sure the code of the Spring Boot app is working. When I change the IP of `return new LettuceConnectionFactory("10.51.5.2", 30315);`: to

1. a regular Redis on my laptop ("localhost", 6379),
2. a dockerized Redis on my laptop,
3. a dockerized Redis on prem, all are working fine.

Therefore, I am quite puzzled what did I do wrong with the setup of this Redis in AWS.
What should I do in order to connect to it properly.
May I get some help please?

Thank you

Comment: Are you testing in the same VPC? Is there a route to 10.51.5.2? Are security groups correct? Can you show `kubectl describe service redis`?

Comment: IP of service `10.x.x.x` is within a private network (IP starting with 10.x / 127.x / 192.x are for private networks), so your Redis won't be reachable from global internet. What is the Kubernetes cluster setup? (EKS ? Other?) What ingress controller did you use? The issue is how your K8S cluster accept incoming connection from internet. With this info we'll be able to help a bit more.

Comment: @PatPanda, are you deploying the Spring Boot microservice in the same namespace that Redis is also deployed? I wonder if they are not ending up as different deployments and then network connectivity is becoming a problem. Also, if you are trying to run this code from outside the K8S namespace, mind that you need to forward the `30315` port to the outside world to be reacheable. Or use the built-in K8S load balancer for this.

Comment: Hello @RicardoFerreira, thank you for your answer. You are correct, I am trying to run the code from outside the K8S namespace. And you are also correct, if I forward the port after using a simple clusterIP, without Load Balancer, it works!!! But this is a bit confusing. I would have expected the fact that I am using a Load Balancer, I would still be able to connect to it from outside the namespace, without any port forwarding. What did I miss?

Comment: Make sense then. Using a LB doesn't necessarily open the network interfaces for connectivity, just expose the ports to the outside world. When you run the code locally, you don't have network boundaries between the microservice and Redis, but when deployed using K8S on AWS—you need to take care of those interactions by enabling ports and traffic with things like security groups. So in other words: your interface is exposed by the LB, but traffic may not be allowed.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification @RicardoFerreira. May I ask: 1) "Using a LB doesn't necessarily open the network interfaces for connectivity" -> How may I open the network interfaces for connectivity please? 2) "you need to take care of those interactions by enabling ports and traffic with things like security groups" -> How do I enable those please?

Comment: @PatPanda, you need to first run your microservice in the same VPC that runs the Redis instance, which is arguably where your K8S is deployed. Assuming that you are using EKS to deploy these pods, you must have a security group created for it. Edit that security group to enable the port that Redis exposes. More information here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/sec-group-reqs.html

Comment: Thank you @RicardoFerreira for the clarification. When you said: "you need to first run your microservice in the same VPC that runs the Redis instance" -> The goal is for Redis to be in my namespace, but for some 70+ microservice which I do not control, deployed outside of my namespace, to get the data that is inside my namespace. The data is not sensitive, the more people consuming (from outside the cluster) it the better. I cannot ask each and every services to be deployed where the redis is unfortunately.

Comment: I am trying to expose this Redis to the outside world, I thought this I could achieve it with the ```type: Load Balancer```. So there is no way for microservices from outside the namespace to access to this redis inside the namespace? @RicardoFerreira

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? Facing the same and not being able to solve. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default, Redis [binds itself](https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/unstable/redis.conf#L87) to the IP addresses `127.0.0.1` and `::1`  and does not accept connections against non-local interfaces. Chances are high that this is your main issue and you may want to review your `redis.conf` file to bind Redis to the interface you need or to the generic `* -::*`, as explained in the comments of the config file itself (which I have linked above).

With that being said, Redis also does not accept connections on non-local interfaces if the default user has no password - a security layer named *Protected mode*. Thus you should either give your default user a password or disable [protected mode](https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/unstable/redis.conf#L111) in your `redis.conf` file.

Not sure if this applies to your case but, as a side note, I would suggest to always avoid exposing Redis to the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing 2 things.
To enable this service for pods in different namespaces you do not need external load balancer, you can just try to use redis.namespace-name:6379 dns name and it will just work. Such dns is there for every service you create (but works only inside kubernetes)
Kubernetes will make sure that your traffic will be routed to proper pods (assuming there is more than one).

If you want to expose redis from outside of kubernetes then you need to make sure there is connectivity from the outside and then you need network load balancer that will forward traffic to your kubernetes service (in your case node port, so you need NLB with eks worker nodes: 30315 as a targets)

If your worker nodes have public IP and their SecurityGroups allow connecting to them directly, you could try to connect to worker node's IP directly just to test things out (without LB).

And regardless off yout setup you can always create proxy via kubectl

```
kubectl port-forward -n redisNS svc/redis 6379:6379
```

and connect from spring boot app to localhost:6379

How do you want to connect from app to redis in a final setup?